# How does useState() in React Hooks know which Component instance it is?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

[React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-does-react-associate-hook-calls-with-components) says:

> #### How does React associate Hook calls with components?
>
> React keeps track
>   of the currently rendering component. Thanks to the Rules of Hooks, we
>   know that Hooks are only called from React components (or custom Hooks
>   — which are also only called from React components). There is an
>   internal list of “memory cells” associated with each component.
>   They’re just JavaScript objects where we can put some data. When you
>   call a Hook like useState(), it reads the current cell (or initializes
>   it during the first render), and then moves the pointer to the next
>   one. This is how multiple useState() calls each get independent local
>   state.

First of all... what is this "memory cell"? Can we print it out ourselves to see its value?

Second, there is only **one** instance of the function (such as `Counter()` in the following example). So if we render `<Counter />` twice into the DOM, once to `<div id="root1">` and the second time to `<div id="root2">`, how does the function `Counter()` know which is which?

```
function Counter() {

    let [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> + </button>                    
            { count }
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}> - </button> 
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You are essentially invoking the function `Counter` 2 times when rendering 2 instances of it. React assigns a unique key to a component. So the first thing is you have two instances of this component running. The next part is `useState` is local to a component's instance. So for each instance of a component you render they each have their own local state. This is similar in concept to a class component's state.

Comment: @JohnRuddell every time new content is shown for this component, Counter() is called. It can be called 5000 times

Comment: Not sure what the question is in that statement. When a component re-renders it will execute. `React.useState` is created once and then reused in subsequent renders. Think of it like how you would memoize something.

Comment: I know how to use it.  I just don't know how it can be implemented

Comment: well i'd look at the source if I want to know more about how it works. you can see the definition of `useState` [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L78). and then the dispatcher is getting assigned in a few places like [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f7278034de5a289571f26666e6717c4df9f519ad/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L399). if you notice the `memoizedState` i think that'll give you a clue :)

Comment: Not sure this "React assigns a unique key to a component. So the first thing is you have two instances of this component running" is true  as the return mount only one component with 2 button that call 2 setCounter, so there are 2 Counters and not 2 components

Comment: @nonopolarity have you then found or implemented those JS objects? For me memory cell seems refer to either virtual memory that map the actual hardware, but most probably are "virtual" so also objects

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have two of your counters inside a parent container JSX:

```xml
<div>
  <Counter/>
  <Counter/>
</div>
```

This is how React can 'know which is which' (extremely simplified):

```js
const componentStates = [ { value: 13 }, { value: 27 } ]; //"memory cells"
let context;

// the parent container JSX will be transformed/executed in this way:
function render() {
    context = componentStates[0];
    Counter();

    context = componentStates[1];
    Counter();
}

function useState() {
    return [ context.value, updateFunction ];
}

function updateFunction(newValue) {
    context.value = newValue;
    render();
}
```

A key concept to understand this is, that `React.useState` is *not* a [pure function](https://dev.to/kjdowns/what-s-a-pure-function-205e), it relies on the rendering context.